# Why I obtain this WP_Query strange behavior trying to select posts having a specific tag?

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, query, query-posts

I have the following problem with **featured tag posts**

I have a page of a website in wich I want to show only the posts that have setted a specific tag (using the loop).

So in this page I have put this loop code:

```
<header class="header-sezione">
    <?php
        echo"<h1>IN EVIDENZA:</h1>";

            $featured = new WP_Query('tag=featured');

            if ($featured->have_posts()) : 
                while ($featured->have_posts()) : $featured->the_post();
                /*
                 * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                 * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part('content', get_post_format());

            endwhile;
            //wp_reset_postdata();
            else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part('content', 'none');

            endif;
    ?>
</header>
```

In theory this loop should show only the post having the **featured** tag set but it works partialy because it corrctly displays all the posts having the **featured** tag set but when there is a single post it shows it also when this post doesn't have the  **featured** tag set.

I can't understand why it happens because I am specifying that have to select only the featured tag by this query:

```
$featured = new WP_Query('tag=featured');
```

What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Tnx

Comment: Are these standard WP tags? Or a custom taxonomy?

Comment: @vancoder it is a standard tag